# Could i make this Jquery resize function more efficient / shorter / cleaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to Jquery and it doesn't look efficient copying the same code in two functions.
Is it possible to make this function more efficient?
By efficient i mean shrinking the code.

What it does is, changing the size of an ID element when it will be resized.
Why i need copy it twice? When i leave the code inside .resize and remove the other inside .ready, the elements will have unset sizes.
It works like i would have it working, but the problem is it doesn't look "clean".

I'm using latest Jquery.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var files = ["home.html","test.html","random.html","noob.html"];
  var a = 0;
  var wh = $(window).height();
  var ww = $(window).width();
  var btn_n = $("#btn_nav button");
    btn_n.height(ww*0.05);
    btn_n.width(ww*0.12);
  $(window).resize(function() {
  var wh = $(window).height();
  var ww = $(window).width();
  var btn_n = $("#btn_nav button");
    btn_n.height(ww*0.05);
    btn_n.width(ww*0.12);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why my question gets a disslike... would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the code you want to run in multiple places into a function, then call it on document ready, and on resize events.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var files = ["home.html","test.html","random.html","noob.html"];
  var a = 0;

  function layout() {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var btn_n = $("#btn_nav button");
    btn_n.height(ww*0.05);
    btn_n.width(ww*0.12);
  }
  layout();
  $(window).resize(layout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic into a named function - then call it on page load and then again on window resize.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  updateSizes();
  var files = ["home.html","test.html","random.html","noob.html"];
  var a = 0;
  $(window).resize(updateSizes)

  function updateSizes(){
   var wh = $(window).height();
   var ww = $(window).width();
   var btn_n = $("#btn_nav button");
     btn_n.height(ww*0.05);
     btn_n.width(ww*0.12);
  }
});
```